# Why is my code not working properly?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to run an ARM assembly code on my raspberry pi4 but it does not work properly:

```
.data
  buffer: .space 40  @ Adjust the buffer size as needed
  welcome_message: .asciz "Welcome! This game was created by Ahmed Imran Naeem (6779560).\n"
  input_prompt: .asciz "Please enter your guess (1-99): "
  low_message: .asciz "Your guess is too low.\n\n"
  high_message: .asciz "Your guess is too high.\n\n"
  invalid_message: .asciz "Invalid input. Please enter a valid number between 1 and 99.\n\n"
  duplicate_message: .asciz "You've already guessed that number. Please try again.\n\n"
  win_message: .asciz "Congratulations! You guessed the number correctly.\n\n"
  lose_message: .asciz "You have lost the game. The secret number was %d.\n\n"
  quit_message: .asciz "Do you want to continue? Press 'y' to continue or 'q' to quit"
  fmt_int: .asciz "%d"

.text
  .global main

.extern printf, scanf, rand  @ Declare external C library functions

@ Custom input function
read_string:
  stmfd sp!, {r4, r5, lr}  @ Save registers

  mov r4, r0                @ r4 = buffer
  mov r5, r1                @ r5 = max length

read_loop:
  ldrb r0, [r4]             @ Read a character
  cmp r0, #10               @ Check if it's a newline
  beq end_read

  cmp r0, #0                @ Check if it's null terminator
  beq end_read

  cmp r5, #0                @ Check if max length reached
  beq end_read

  strb r0, [r4], #1         @ Store the character and move buffer pointer
  sub r5, r5, #1            @ Decrement remaining length
  b read_loop

end_read:
  strb r4, [r4]             @ Store null terminator
  ldmfd sp!, {r4, r5, pc}   @ Restore registers and return

main:
  @ Display welcome message
  ldr r0, =welcome_message
  bl printf

  @ Generate a random number between 1 and 99
  mov r1, #1
  mov r2, #99
  bl rand
  mov r3, r0

  @ Initialize number of guesses
  mov r4, #0

  @ Clear the buffer
  ldr r0, =buffer
  mov r1, #40
  mov r2, #0
  bl memset

game_loop:
  @ Check if the number of tries exceeds 6
  cmp r4, #6
  bge lose_condition

  @ Prompt the player to enter their guess
  ldr r0, =input_prompt
  bl printf  @ Use printf for output

  @ Read user input
  ldr r0, =buffer
  ldr r1, =fmt_int  @ Load the format string for integer
  bl scanf          @ Read integer and store in r0

  @ Check if the input is within the valid range
  cmp r0, #1
  blt invalid_input
  cmp r0, #99
  bgt invalid_input

  @ Check for duplicate guesses
  mov r5, #0        @ Counter for loop
check_duplicates:
  ldr r6, [buffer, r5, lsl #2]  @ Load previous guesses
  cmp r0, r6        @ Compare with previous guesses
  beq duplicate_guess
  add r5, r5, #1    @ Increment counter
  cmp r5, r4        @ Compare counter with number of guesses
  bne check_duplicates

  @ Store the current guess in the buffer
  str r0, [buffer, r4, lsl #2]

  @ Increment number of guesses
  add r4, r4, #1

  @ Check if the user's guess is correct
  cmp r0, r3
  beq win_condition

  @ Check if the user's guess is too low
  cmp r0, r3
  blt low_condition

  @ Check if user's guess is too high
  cmp r0, r3
  bgt high_condition

  b game_loop

high_condition:
  @ User's guess is too high
  ldr r0, =high_message
  bl printf
  b game_loop

low_condition:
  @ User's guess is too low
  ldr r0, =low_message
  bl printf
  b game_loop

lose_condition:
  @ Player loses if they reach 6 tries
  ldr r0, =lose_message
  bl printf
  b prompt_play_again

win_condition:
  @ Player wins if their guess is correct
  ldr r0, =win_message
  bl printf
  b prompt_play_again

duplicate_guess:
  @ Inform player about duplicate guess
  ldr r0, =duplicate_message
  bl printf
  b game_loop

invalid_input:
  @ Inform player about invalid input
  ldr r0, =invalid_message
  bl printf
  b game_loop

prompt_play_again:
  @ Prompt the player to play again or quit
  ldr r0, =quit_message
  bl printf

  @ Read player's choice from the terminal
  ldr r0, =fmt_int
  ldr r1, =buffer
  bl scanf
  ldr r0, =buffer  @ Load the player's choice from the buffer

  @ Check if the player wants to quit
  cmp r0, #'q'
  beq quit_game

  @ Check if the player wants to play again
  cmp r0, #'y'
  bne game_loop

quit_game:
  @ Exit the program
  mov r0, #0
  mov r7, #1  @ Use the exit system call code
  swi #0       @ Make the system call

.end
```

It does not assemble properly and if by some miracle it does it give Segmentation error on runtime.

Comment: `it does not work properly` is a vague, useless description of the program behavior ... what do you expect the program to do? ... what does it do? ... what errors do you get? ... please update your question ... **do not** write a comment